# Reading the cow Shadow storage directly

Tags: copy-on-write, volume-shadow-service

How to read only the changed blocks from the shadow storage as illustrated here?

http://macriumsoftware.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/reading_data_back.png

I want to know if someone can share a sample how to read the cow Shadow storage directly from the windows providor vss.
This to detect which original blocks has changed; and to read it's consistent data.
Or if someone has a code example of a Vss provider code that performs copy-on-write?
Regards Tomas